Altium designer DRC Configuration
In my schematic, I have jumpers to separate the power of an IC from the supply rails as follows:

I have many of these jumpers in my circuit, when I run DRC, it says all the Vn net should be connected together (Vn-IN and Vp-IN are connected to the main rail in the PCB, Vn, and Vp is connected to the chip supply pins):

But in fact, it is not needed, how can I fix these types of errors in the DRC configurations?

Hi, When I look at you picture they look like they have the same net name "Vn".
So not really sure how the diagram snippet and layout fits?

@ Tyassin you mean I need to make it like Vn-1, Vn-2,...Vp-1, Vp-2,....? I think I will fix the issue.

Actually now that I look at your schematic you have two connectors J4 and J5.
In your layout you show J4 and J23? Maybe that is just an example.  But can you show the schematic pin names and the corresponding layout?

Select that pin in schematics and make it a "No ERC" connection.
Place » Directives » Generic No ERC. This will exclude that pin from checking.
Refer to the doc: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-no-erc?version=21
